# Netherland refugee passport

Tags: passports, international-travel, netherlands, refugees

I'm a refugee in Netherland from Kenya. I want to travel back to Kenya for an emergency visit. I cannot use my Kenyan passport and I fear using my refugee passport issued by Netherland government because I hear that you cannot use it to visit your country of origin. The reason why I don't fear going back to Kenya is because it safe for me if I only stay there for few days...my reason for seeking asylum in the Netherland is a little bit unique. My question is, are Netherland refugee passport holders allowed to use it to travel to their countries of origin?

Comment: If your asylum reasons are so **unique** why don’t you use it and see what the Netherlands authorities will say?

Comment: Some countries will seize refugee travel documents, or even the refugee, at the border if the refugee returns to that country. It might not be safe to return for even a moment if you travel on a refugee travel document.

Comment: You're a refugee. If you can travel without fear of your life to your country of origin you have no right to hold that refugee status.

Comment: @jwenting that's a bit strong.  There could be circumstances under which a temporary return could be safe even though a permanent return would not be.  But I'm surprised nobody has said the obvious: do not try this without first talking to a lawyer who is experienced with refugee law in the Netherlands.

Comment: @phoog Good point, I will update my answer

Comment: @phoog as a refugee by definition it's so unsafe in your home country you can no longer be there at all. You can certainly not be there legally, known to your government. Maybe crossing the border illegally from a neighbouring country might work for a short while but arriving at an international border crossing would get your arrested instantly and off to the torture chamber. If that's not going to happen, you don't qualify for refugee status.

Comment: @jwenting we all know that legal definitions do not necessarily reflect reality.  Refugees are not necessarily fleeing their government; it's possible that they cannot rely on the government for protection from some non-governmental persecutor.  Such a person can indeed make themselves known to the government without fear of being persecuted by the government, yet still qualifies for refugee status.

Answer (score 11):

No, you can use it to travel to countries outside the Netherlands, but not to travel to your country of origin. https://www.arnhem.nl/Inwoners/english/Identification/Refugee_passport

If you have a compelling reason for wanting to do this, you should consult an Immigration lawyer with experience in refugee law in the Netherlands before you attempt to travel.

Answer (score 3):

You should ask who issued the refugee passport.

In general you cannot return in your origin country (as the answer of @traveller, and link). There are very few exceptional cases, which are discussed before you take the travel, to issuing authority. Do no count about it.